# Proper use of Reflection and binding flags

Tags: c#, reflection, bindingflags

I want to modify the below code to be able to use a private method

```
        //use reflection to Load the data
    var method =
                    typeof(MemberDataFactory)
                    .GetMethod("LoadData")
                    .MakeGenericMethod(new [] { data.GetType() })
                    .Invoke(this, null);
```

Ive tried the following with no luck:

```
        //use reflection to Load the data
    var method =
                    typeof(MemberDataFactory)
                    .GetMethod("LoadData")
                    .MakeGenericMethod(new [] { data.GetType() })
                    .Invoke(this, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null , null, null);
```

Also what is "var" in terms of this code? Id prefer to specify its type instead of using var.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? Have you got an exception? Or code did not compile?

Comment: `var` is implicit typing, but it is completely static, not dynamic.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx (contrast dynamic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)?

Comment: The flags should be used for `GetMethod`, not `Invoke`

Comment: Null reference exception, the first code I posted works fine on public methods. The second gives a null reference exception when used on a private method

Comment: @KooKiz that was the problem, could you post it as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: @TimS. sorry I got the terminology wrong, but I meant that instead of var I want to specify its type.

Comment: Im not a 100% sure why someone just down voted me, I see this as a legitimate question.

Comment: @Serg Rogovtsev I know what var means, I meant what is its type as it refers to the code, it could be a string, an int or something else. I always like to specify its type instead of using var.

Comment: @MichaelTaylor3D then go on and specify it, what stops you?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I wasnt sure what type the reflection code returns. A very similiar code returns of type MemberInfo, not this one. I was hoping someone who was knowledgeable in reflection know what type that code returns.

Comment: @MichaelTaylor3D MSDN very clearly [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k9x6bc0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that `Invoke` returns `object`. Besides you can simply hold your mouse over `var` in Visual Studio and see type in tooltip. (And no, no similar code could return `MethodInfo`.)

Comment: @SergRogovtsev putting aside several false assumptions your making, Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MichaelTaylor3D which "false assumptions" do you mean?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev It doesn't matter, its all beyond the scope of this question. But your information was vital in helping me solve my dilemma. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332483%28v=vs.71%29) of `Type.GetMethod()`, which is where you pass your binding flags. The default `.GetMethod(string)` only looks for public methods, so it returns null, hence your null reference exception.

Your code should be something more like:

```
var method =
        typeof(MemberDataFactory)
        .GetMethod("LoadData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) // binding flags go here
        ...
```